# jQuery - Complete loading animation on each individual image?

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently using jQuery to manipulate a loading placeholder image that covers loading thumbnails on my website.  Basically, the script waits for the page to finish loading, and then hides the loading animation.  You can see the effect at my site, [here](http://element17.com/index.php?level=album&id=42).

On a page that has many images to load, however, it can take quite some time before the thumbnails appear.

I had considered using some sort of lazy-loading technique, but I think it might be simpler to just switch the trigger for the loading animation hiding from the completion of the loading of the entire page to just the completion of loading of each particular image.  I have give this a shot with the following script:

`<script type="text/javascript">
$('div[id^="photo"]').load(function() {
$(this+"_loading").fadeOut('slow');
});
</script>`

It doesn't seem to be working, though.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure this is run when the DOM, and before the page loads. Have you tried your code in multiple browsers? Also, shouldn't the load function be on the img tags and not the divs?

Comment: the first argument for the load function should be the URL to load, then the function callback comes second: $('div[id^="photo"]').load('someurl.html', function() { $(this+"_loading").fadeOut('slow'); });

Comment: @davidosomething, I just wants to hook onto the load event, not change the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the jQuery docs @ http://api.jquery.com/load-event/:

"This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object."

Bind you load event to the image itself, and find the corresponding loading text from the callback function.

```
$(function(){
   $('div[id^="photo"] img').load(function(){
      $(this).closest('div').find('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
   });

   $('div[id^="photo"] img').each(function(){
      var src = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src','#');
      $(this).attr('src',src);
   });
});
```

This code above allows minor rearrangement of your markup.

You also have to make sure to bind the load event in your ready function, after your DOM is ready and jQuery has loaded. Inline script elements are executed as soon as they're parsed.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the jQuery docs above, there are several caveats that make this unreliable in certain browsers, sometimes this event doesn't fire for images already in the cache, and on webkit it doesn't fire if you change the image src to the same value as before. There is an interesting point in this forum thread about it: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/image-load-event-some-progress

I edited the code above to add some workarounds, although it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work either... You can see the source in your browser, can't you?

Comment: This seems to be closer but I guess it must be affecting some of the divs before the corresponding image loads, as if I clear my cache I see some of the images loading after the corresponding loading image has disappeared.

Comment: I found an interesting article on google. Although it's a bit dated, the issue still seems to exist. Edited my post.

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted some stuff and this is now working how I'd like it to.  Thanks very much for your help!